# Easier way to get last item in Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

There's got to be an easier way to do what I came up with here:

```
int lastDayInList = ddlBirthDay.Items.IndexOf(ddlBirthDay.Items[ddlBirthDay.Items.Count -1]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you the last item in a drop down list.

```
ListItem lastItem = ddlBirthDay.Items[ddlBirthDay.Items.Count-1]
```

In your code, it looks like you are getting the index of the last item. However, the accessible index of the last item will be -1 of the count.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .net v3.5 then Linq is an option, too.

```
ListItem latItem = ddlBirthday.Items.Last();
ListItem latItem = ddlBirthday.Items.LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: I put Last() in there.  This solution is .NET 3.5.  Last() is not recognized on an asp.net dropdownlist.  Are you saying this is a Linq method?

Comment: yes, this IS a linq method.  could be that ddlBirthdays.Items is not an IEnumerable.  also, dont forget to #include the namespace System.Linq